# How would a get part of an error string (MODULE_NOT_FOUND)?

Tags: node.js

I'm wanting to make some that would automate halve of my work load but unsure how to get the part I require to progress:

On each error of `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` I want to grab the information from this error:

EG: `Error: Cannot find module 'hastebin-gen'`; the part I want to retrieve from the error is `'hastebin-gen'`

How would I get the information inbetween the single quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help a friend - [Dracovian](https://github.com/Dracovian)

I have also made a NPM out of this script which can be found [here](https://npmjs.com/package/lazyinstaller)

Repository of this can be found [here](https://github.com/CyberCDN/Lazy-Installer)

```js
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    let regex = /Error\: Cannot find module \'(.*)\'/ig;
    error = error.toString();
    let matched = error.match(regex);
    if (matched) {
        let package = error.split(regex)[1];
        console.log(package);
    }
});
```